# TouchableWithoutFeedback with custom component inside doesn't fires onPress callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I made a **[DEMO](https://rnplay.org/plays/iBVgwg)**

so the problem is that third button isn't working. The only difference between buttons is the way I passed them in Header component.

```
<Header secondButton={<View style={styles.button}><Text>Second Button</Text></View>}
        thirdButton={<ThirdButton />}
        onPress={this._handlePress} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answered by @brentvatne on [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1352#issuecomment-106938999)

> I was able to fix it in [this example](https://rnplay.org/plays/2iBPdA?autoplay=true) - notice that I changed the
>   `<View>` in your `ThirdButton` to include `{...this.props}`
>
> ```
> <View style={styles.button} {...this.props}>
>   .. etc
> </View>
> ```
>
> The reason for this is that `TouchableWithoutFeedback` will set responder
>   props on that component, but `ThirdButton` is just a composite component
>   with no backing `UIView`, so I want to pass those on to the `View`.
>   [See what I'm talking about here](https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native/blob/fix-stacktrace-parser-dependency/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableWithoutFeedback.js#L79-L90)

Answer (score 9):

My solution was to turn this ...

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={props.onPress}>
  <Contents {...props} />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

into this...

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={props.onPress}>
  <View>
    <Contents {...props} />
  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Comment: If the developer wanna have more than one component inside `TouchableWithoutFeedback`, all components should be wrapped inside a `View`, and it is necessary for firing events. thanks @KirkStrobeck