# React-Native How to handle onPress from Item in flatlist ???

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

My FlatList is stateless component, and when item pressed I want to handle onPress by call method "handleOnPress". How can I do it ?? 
the below is sample codes.
`

```
handleOnPress = () => {
  .....
}
<SampleListView
    data={prop.data}
    onPress={this.handleOnPress}
/>
const SampleListView = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <FlatList
        style={styles.container}
        data={props.data}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={renderItem}
    />
    )
}
renderItem = ({ item }: { item: DataSample }) => {
  return (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={ () => props.onPress}>
      ....
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )
}
```

`

Comment: Maybe this will help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177077/react-native-flatlist-onpress-for-child

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this out?

```
handleOnPress = () => {
  .....
}
<SampleListView
    data={prop.data}
    onPress={this.handleOnPress}
/>
const SampleListView = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <FlatList
        style={styles.container}
        data={props.data}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={renderItem}
    />
    )
}
renderItem = ({ item }: { item: DataSample }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={props.onPress}>
      <View>
        ....
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )
}
```

Please pay attention to that 2 links.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

[TouchableWithoutFeedback with custom component inside doesn't fires onPress callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349140/touchablewithoutfeedback-with-custom-component-inside-doesnt-fires-onpress-call)

The differences are, giving callback as param and adding View layer.

Answer (score 3):

Problem with your code is this `onPress={props.onPress}` your `renderItem` function does not know (props) all it knows are the item parameter passed to it.

If you do this

```
onPress={() => alert("clicked")}
```

it will work. Either pass onPress function through your data or bind your `renderItem` function in your constructor and then call

```
onPress={() => this.props.onPress()}
```

Comment: How can I fix it ? @ArkaneKhan

Answer (score 0):

```
<FlatList
    style={styles.container}
    data={props.data}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
    renderItem={ ({ item }) => (
     <SomeComponent
       title={item.title}
       onPress={ () => pressHandler() }
     /> 
    )}
/>
```

So, basically in "renderItem" you pass the component that will be assigned to every "item" iteration. E.g. you have blog posts data, "renderItem" component will represent the layout of each one of the posts (item).

This means that you can set onPress on that component (e.g. <SomeComponent onPress={ () => pressHandler() } />), and pass the handler function to this onPress prop.

You can even pass an argument to this handler like:

```
<FlatList
  style={styles.container}
  data={props.data}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
  renderItem={ ({ item }) => (
   <SomeComponent
     title={item.title}
     onPress={ () => pressHandler(item.id) }
   /> 
  )}
 />
```

Keep in mind that your data object needs to have this "id" or "_id" or "uid" or something else, but you definitely need to refer to this "id" from the "item" object, because every single instance of the data you're iterating, it's automatically mapped to the "item" object.

Once this is passed to the child component ( SomeComponent /> ), you can access that like:

```
export const SomeComponent = ({ title, onPress }) => {

 return (
   <Pressable onPress={onPress}>
      [...some content here]
   </Pressable>
 );

};
```

Instead of Pressable, you can try something else, but I've found that onPress on View may not work properly, and "Pressable" will be more future-proof in your app.